# recognizing multiple entries within a cell formula in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a usoft Excel 2007 spreadsheet with names down the first column and dates across the top row for each column.  Payments are made from people on dates specified in the column headings.  The amount of the payment is entered at the intersection of the name and date.  Sometimes more than one check is received on a specific date and I just add the two amounts in the cell for that date.  However, I would like to count the number of checks received during a specific date and can't do it simply by using the count function because the cells with more than one check cannot be determined.

Comment: How are you adding multiple amounts? Are you taking a new line or using a comma or space between each amount?  There should be a way to count the commas, spaces or carriage returns.  Or if you have used the currency symbol $ then you could count that.

Comment: I am accomplishing this now by using 3D formulas.  =sum(first worksheet:last worksheet!cell range) to keep total of checks and =count(worksheet range!cell range) to keep count of multiple checks on a specific date.  Don't know if there is a more elegant way.

Comment: However, now I am accomplishing this now by using 3D formulas.  =sum(first worksheet:last worksheet!cell range) to provide total of checks and =count(worksheet range!cell range) to keep count of multiple checks on a specific date.  So I just enter the new check on a subsequent sheet.  Subsequent sheets just have the additional checks.  So now, on the top sheet I have the check totals and the number of checks.  Don't know if there is a more elegant way though.